# how to use whole one folder and part of another folder as resources in gradle

Tags: gradle

My project structure is:

```
src/
  main/
    resources/
      A.jpg
      A.gif
    text/
      A.text
      A.doc   /*unwanted*/
```

How to configure build.gradle to get final jar with A.gif, A.jpg, A.txt?

I want treat as main resources all files from `src/main/resources/` and all `*.txt` files from `src/main/text/`

For

```
sourceSets.main.resources {
    srcDir 'src/main/resources'
    srcDir 'src/main/text'
```

I get in final jar unwanted A.doc

For

```
sourceSets.main.resources {
    srcDir 'src/main/resources'
    srcDir 'src/main/text'
    include '*.txt'
```

I have final jar with only A.txt

#### UPDATE

However given simple example can be solved in alternative way with *exclude*, I'm looking for solution when resources consists of one whole folder and part of second folder (in Maven it is easy)

Comment: use an exclude instead of an include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an exclude that applies to all srcDirs like this:

```
sourceSets.main.resources {
  srcDir 'src/main/resources'
  srcDir 'src/main/text'
  exclude'*.doc'
}
```

The inlcudes and excludes cannot be selectively applied to a srcDir, they take effect across all srcDirs in that sourceSet.